# Freemarker condition #if not working, using XDocReport

Tags: freemarker, docx, xdocreport

I am trying a hello world with Freemarker using xdocreport and put a condition in the docx file, but it does not work.
I tried:

```
[#if name?has_content]
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
[/#if]

<#if name?has_content>
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
</#if>

[#if name??]
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
[/#if]

<#if name??>
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
</#if>
```

The replacing fields is working fine but not the conditional fields. The output is exactly the same as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from with your docx which doesn't use mergefield. You must use mergefield to write any Freemarker directive, otherwise MS Word will escape your directive with XML characters (and your Freemarker directive will not work like your problem).

Note you have already posted this question question at https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/detail?id=285

Comment: yes, I forgot to close this question, thank you Angelo again.

Answer (score 0):

OK with mergefield :

```
[#if name?has_content]
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
[/#if]

[#if name??]
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
[/#if]
```

KO for me with mergefield

```
<#if name?has_content>
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
</#if>

<#if name??>
Sdfsdfsdf sdf sdf 
</#if>
```

Comment: I cannot tell whether you are describing a problem you have and want help with... or are trying to provide an answer to the question at the top of the page, according to [answer]. Please [edit] to make that more obvious - or delete the post (for which you would have to register first ... or flag your own post to have a moderator do the deleting for you).